# graph is Hamiltonian if the number of vertices with degree at most d is less that d

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

A graph, $|G| \geq 3$ such that $\forall d < n/2$ ,  $|\{v \in V(G) : deg(v) \leq d\}| < d $  then G has a Hamilton cycle.

I'm not sure where to start, or what the second requirement suggests.